# Load data in view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a simple controller function that fetch all records from db. but when i am trying to show all these records it show nothing. In fact it shows me hard coded foreach loop like this.

```
 @foreach ($compactData as $value) {{ $value->Name }} @endforeach
```

this is my contoller function.

```
public function showallProducts()
{
    $productstock = Product::all()->stocks;
    $productoldprice = Product::all()->OldPrices;
    $productcurrentprice = Product::all()->CurrentPrice;
    $compactData=array('productstock', 'productoldprice', 'productcurrentprice');
    return view('welcome', compact($compactData));
}
```

this is my view

```
       <!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>


 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                Laravel
            </div>

            <div class="title m-b-md">
                All products
            </div>


            <table>

                <tbody>
                @foreach ($compactData as $value)
                    {{ $value->Name }}

                @endforeach

                </tbody>


            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

why it is behaving like this. any solution?? I am using phpstorm version 17. Is their any setting issue to run project because what ever project I ran it gives me the only page which i ran with only html?
My route is.

```
   Route::get('/', function () {

    $action = 'showallProducts';
    return App::make('ProductController')->$action();
 });
```

Comment: Does it actually show you the `@foreach ($compactData as $value) {{ $value->Name }} @endforeach` in the browser source?

Comment: yes it prints the the @foreach loop in the browser source. when i try to run my porject

Comment: Then you're not running it properly. You need to run your laravel project within a web server. If you don't already have one locally, Laravel's Homestead VM is a great solution. If you're already running it with a web server, then you'll need to check the server's configuration to find out why it's not parsing the PHP code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: The quickest and simplest way is to use Laravel Valet :)

Comment: no its not duplicate

Comment: I have local webserver apache installed.

Comment: How are you accessing that page? What's the address in the address bar?

Comment: are your sure your view is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have a problem with your web server.

Try to use [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/valet) as development environnement.

**Edit** : I found this : [Valet for Windows](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows)

Comment: Is it for windows??

Comment: I sadly don't think so :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your `$compactData` variable? Please `dd($compactData)` to see what it contains.

**Problem 1**

You are accessing a relational property as a property of Eloquent collection, like this:

`Product::all()->stocks`

which is not correct. Because the Collection object doesn't have the property `stocks` but yes the `Product` object might have a stocks property. Please read the Laravel documentation about Collection.

**Problem 2**

`$compactData = array('productstock', 'productoldprice', 'productcurrentprice');`

This line creating an array of 4 string, **plain string** not variable. So, your `$compactData` is containing an array of 4 string. If you want to have a variable with associative array then you need to do the following:

`$compactData = compact('productstock', 'productoldprice', 'productcurrentprice');`

**Problem 3**

```
return view('welcome', compact($compactData));
```

Here you are trying to pass the `$compactDate` to the `welcome` view but unfortunately `compact()` function doesn't accept variable but the string name of that variable as I have written in **Problem 2**. So, it should be:

```
return view('welcome', compact('compactData'));
```

**Problem 4**

Finally, in the blade you are accessing each element of the `$compactData` data variable and print them as string which might be an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't mention the `blade` in the name of the view file by which it is saved. So change the name of the file by which it is save to something like:

```
filename.blade.php
```

and try again.

Explanation:

`@foreach ($compactData as $value)` this is the syntax of blade template engine, and to parse and excute it, you have to mention the `blade` extension in the name.

Comment: no its not working. I think its an issue with php strom setting

Comment: You don't need to use the full filename in Laravel. It automatically looks for the `.blade.php`.

Comment: I am saying to save the file with `blade`

Comment: yes i have save the file with blade exention. infact it is the default page laravel provides when we create new project